# Perl - Use of uninitialized variable $ftp

Tags: perl, ftp, initialization

I am getting an error when running the below perl script. The error reads:

> Use of uninitialized value in die at AfterGauss.pl line 54.

Line 54 is `$ftp->put($fpath1) || die $ftp->message;`. Is there something that anyone sees wrong with my code. I've tried removing the die statements and the 1st ftp just fails. If I rerun the script it runs fine on the second time, but the first always throws me this error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;


#proper date.ini file with fully qualified path
my $dateFile = "C:\\CompOps\\PostApps\\ini\\pDate.ini";

my $date;

#Get Date
open FILE, $dateFile || die "could not open $dateFile";
while(<FILE>) {
    $date = $_;
}
close FILE;

#Trim Date
$date =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

#rdc original filename with path
my $fileName1 = "Y:\\PRODUCTS\\XML\\RDCX$date.XML";
#rdc new filename with path
my $newFileName1 = "Y:\\PRODUCTS\\XML\\rdcx$date.xml";
#rdc new filename with path to $archiveFile1
my $archiveFile1 = "Y:\\PRODUCTS\\XML\\Archive\\rdcx$date.xml";
#rom original filename with path
my $fileName2 = "W:\\BBSDATA\\ROMX$date.ZIP";
#rom new filename with path
my $newFileName2 = "W:\\BBSDATA\\romx$date.zip";

#rdc file with path to post from
my $fpath1 = $newFileName1;
#rom file with path to post from
my $fpath2 = $newFileName2;

#rename RDC file to lowercase
rename($fileName1, $newFileName1) || die "Cannot rename $fileName1: $!\n";

#rename ROM file to lowercase
rename($fileName2, $newFileName2) || die "Cannot rename $fileName2: $!\n";

# FTP credentials
my $host = "HOST";
my $user = "USERNAME";
my $pass = "PASSWORD";
#directory to post to
my $dir = "/content-inbound-to-rdc";

#ftp rdc file
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) || die "Can't open $host: $@\n";
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($dir);
$ftp->put($fpath1) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
print "rdc ftp successful! ";
print $ftp->message;

#move rdc file to $archive
rename($newFileName1, $archiveFile1) || die "Cannot move rdc file to archive \n";

#update credentials
$host = "HOST";
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";
#update post to path
$dir = '/cedrom';
#ftp rdc file
$ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) || die "Can't open $host: $@\n";
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($dir);
$ftp->put($fpath2) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
print "rom ftp successful! ";
print $ftp->message;
```

Comment: The message seems to refer to `$ftp->message`, that it's returning an `undef`.  What is that method supposed to do, and where does its "message" come from?

Comment: The method gives the ftp message if the statement fails, I'm extremely new to perl and don't know the quirks yet. But this code is almost verbatim from https://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html

Comment: The documentation on the module isn't very enlightening for me, but I guess `$ftp->message` may contain the message, that the server sends, when a command failed. Possibly it's `undef` when the server didn't or couldn't send a message, e.g. due to an interrupted connection. That strange behaviour, that it works the second time might further indicate some weird network problem (something "woke up" along the path by the first attempt). Maybe you can connect, plug the cable, try issuing a command and see if `$ftp->message` is `undef` in that case?

Comment: What do you mean, "plug the cable"?

Comment: @stickybit I think you're right. I really don't think it has anything to do with the script. When I test it on my personal servers it works fine. So that makes me think... Do you or anyone else know of a way to retry the ftp if it fails the first time.. I could just rewrite the logic over again after the first attempt but that would be messy as it would upload the file twice (overriding the first) if the first try was indeed successful. This is probably very simple but I'm very new to perl so maybe you know of an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Did you check that `-f $fpath1` is true before trying to `put` it?  The documentation says that `$ftp->put` returns the remote filename upon success, so maybe you aren't allowed to put files there?

Comment: @xxfelixxx No I'm definitely allowed as it works when I run the script the second time. I think it is something to do with the server... Would there be an easy way in perl to retry if the put fails?

Comment: You could roll your own, or use a library for it, such as Retry: http://search.cpan.org/~tjc/Retry-1.01/lib/Retry.pm

Comment: Or Attempt: http://search.cpan.org/~markf/Attempt-1.01/lib/Attempt.pm

Comment: You could use a `for` loop decrementing a counter, say from e.g. 3 down. Inside execute `$ftp->put($fpath1)` if it succeeded exit the loop with `last`. Otherwise the loop will continue with another attempt. And end when the end of the counter is reached. Then it failed for good.

Comment: @stickybit You’ve been a great help. Can you basically state what you said in your comments in an answer and if you have time provide a simple code example? I believe you solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is caused by some network issue, like an aborted connection. Then `$ftp->message` might be `undef` as the server cannot send any message here. But that's just a guess, the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshay/libnet-3.11/lib/Net/FTP.pm) isn't clear about where `$ftp->message` actually comes from.

The phenomenon, that it works in the second attempt might reinforce that conjecture. Faulty network equipment sometimes "wakes up" after some traffic, which initially failed.

If you want to retry it a few time times, here's a sketch (untested, but should demonstrate the idea):

```
print("put\n");
for (my $counter = 3; $counter; $counter--) {
  if (!$ftp->put($fpath1)) {
    if (defined($ftp->message)) {
      print("Error. Message: $ftp->message\n");
    }
    else {
      print("Error. Message: undef\n");
    }
    print("retrying...\n");
  }
  else {
    last;
  }
}
if (!$counter) {
  print("gave up.\n");
  # further error handling goes here... e.g. abort the script...
}
```

You can remove the

```
    if (defined($ftp->message)) {
      ...
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
```

,

```
if (!$counter) {
  ...
}
```

and the `print()`s if you don't want to handle that or have that output respectively.

Also lower or raise the initial counter value as needed.